# How to attach a file to temporary location before sending a email with attachment?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, email-attachments

I'm having a bit of trouble attaching a chosen file to my VB.net form before pressing my submit button which then sends a email with the attachment.
At the moment, my form can can open a dialog box to browse for file but I receive errors after choosing a file from a location on my machine.
Can anybody help please?  Thanks.
This is the code I've used for the attachment button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openDLG As New OpenFileDialog

    'openDLG.AddExtension = True
    openDLG.ReadOnlyChecked = True
    openDLG.Multiselect = True
    openDLG.Title = "Select the file(s) you want added to the message..."
    openDLG.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"

    If openDLG.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        For Each item As String In openDLG.FileNames

            'Create a new System.NET.Mail.Attachment class instance for each file.
            attachToMsg = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(item)

            'Then add the attachment to your message. You have to do this everytime you run the code
            'above.

            EmailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachToMsg)

        Next

        MsgBox("I have finished adding all of the selected files! You can do more if you want!")

    End If
End Sub
```

Button3 code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using message As New MailMessage()
        'set to the from, to and subject fields
        message.From = (New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text.ToString()))
        message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("NO.ONE@elsewhere.com"))
        message.Subject = "New commission query"

        'code the message body
        Dim MsgBody As String
        MsgBody = TextBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  TextBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  TextBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
                  ComboBox4.Text.ToString() & vbCr
        message.Body = MsgBody
        Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        client.Host = "mailhost"
        client.Send(message)
    End Using
        'display submitted box
        MessageBox.Show("Your request has been submitted!", "Congratulations!")
        'close form
        Me.Close()
  End Sub
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are attaching the filename and not the file stream itself (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds708xx.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 ).

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @yhw42 - There is a filename overload so this should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56wesadc.aspx

Comment: Hi Ciaran, this is the error I get: NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object variable or With block variable not set.  It points at this bit of code: EmailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachToMsg)

Comment: Where do you have defined and initialized EmailMessage variable? Use the debugger and check if that variable is Nothing when you try to add an attachement

Comment: Thanks Steve, a bit of a schoolboy error, forgot to define 'eMailmessage' - Done that by adding "Dim eMailmessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage" and goes through with no errors but doesnt attach the file that I chose before I press the submit button on my form whereby it sends the email.

Comment: @MattWilko - you are right. My bad.

Comment: Which errors you receive?

Comment: Hi SysDragon, I do not receive any errors now. It's just that when I have attached the file, there is another button that I use on the form that submits the data input on the form and sends and outputs it into a email which is received.  The attachment does not appear on the email at all. Any ideas??

Comment: I have added a the submit button code to this thread.  I'm thinking it needs to have some relations to the attachment in this section so that it comes through with the file on the email too.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your "message" object in Button3_Click code and the "EmailMessage" in Button1_Click code ought to be the same "message" object.

As Steve mentions above...

> Where do you have defined and initialized EmailMessage variable? Use the debugger and check if that variable is Nothing when you try to add an attachement – Steve 5 hours ago

Its all a case of WHERE you have DEFINED the EmailMessage object?

Maybe you should declare your EmailMessage object at FORM Level scope and then modify your Button3 code to access THAT SAME EmailMessage Instead of in the Attachment Procedure (Button1_Click code) and also you would need to "Instantiate" your EmailMessage message object before you attempt to modify its properties.

So you would have something along the lines of....

```
'Declarations section (form scope)

Dim TheEmailMessage As New MailMessage()


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim openDLG As New OpenFileDialog

  'openDLG.AddExtension = True
  openDLG.ReadOnlyChecked = True
  openDLG.Multiselect = True
  openDLG.Title = "Select the file(s) you want added to the message..."
  openDLG.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
  If openDLG.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    For Each item As String In openDLG.FileNames
      'Create a new System.NET.Mail.Attachment class instance for each file.
      attachToMsg = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(item)
      'Then add the attachment to your message. 
      'You have to do this everytime you run the code above
      TheEmailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachToMsg)
    Next
    MsgBox("I have finished adding all of the selected files! You can do more if you want!")
  End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
  Using TheEmailMessage

    'set to the from, to and subject fields
    TheEmailMessage.From = (New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text.ToString()))
    TheEmailMessage.[To].Add(New MailAddress("NO.ONE@elsewhere.com"))
    TheEmailMessage.Subject = "New commission query"

    'code the message body
    Dim MsgBody As String
    MsgBody = TextBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
      TextBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
      TextBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
      ComboBox1.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
      ComboBox2.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
      ComboBox3.Text.ToString() & vbCr & _
      ComboBox4.Text.ToString() & vbCr
    TheEmailMessage.Body = MsgBody
    Dim client As New SmtpClient()
    client.Host = "mailhost"
    client.Send(message)
  End Using
  'display submitted box
  MessageBox.Show("Your request has been submitted!", "Congratulations!")
  'close form
  Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Zaf for your suggestions.  This is exactly what I did immediately after Steve's questions.  Just had a memory lapse is all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a temporary file (folder). Here is an example to extract the file from resource, put in a temporary file and open it. Returns the temporary folder used.

```
 Public Overloads Function EXTRACT_FILE_FROM_RESOURCE(ByVal sFile As String, Optional ByVal andStart As Boolean = True) As String

        Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim root As String = assembly.GetName().Name
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(root & "." & sFile)
        Dim buffer(Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length) - 1) As Byte
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        stream.Close()
        Dim sFolderUsed As String = GetTempDirectory()
        Dim sFilePath As String

        sFilePath = IO.Path.Combine(sFolderUsed , sFile )


        Using f As New IO.FileStream(sFilePath , IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            f.Close()
            File.SetAttributes(sFilePath , File.GetAttributes(sFilePath ) And Not FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        End Using

        If andStart Then
            StartProcess(sFilePath )
        End If
        Return sFolderUsed 


    End Function


    Public Function GetTempDirectory() As String
        Dim pathx As String
        Do
            pathx = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath(), IO.Path.GetRandomFileName())
        Loop Until Not Directory.Exists(pathx)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathx)
        Return pathx

    End Function
```